# Filtrar JSON con Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola quería saber como puedo filtrar todos los objetos que tengan el mismo valor en un atributo, y luego pintar el valor de ese atributo. 
Por ejemplo:

```
[
 {
    id: "1",
    description:"Desctiption",
    cost:   13,
    category:"Autos"
  },
  {   
    id: "2",
    description:"Lorem ipsum",
    cost:   15,
    category:"Motos"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    description:"Moto",
    cost:   25,
    category:"Motos"
  },
]
```

lo que yo quiero es que me imprima por ejemplo:

> **Motos**: Lorem ipsum $15, Moto $25.

Quiero hacerlo con un `for`, que cuando las categorías sean las mismas me lo pinte todo en un linea.

Gracias

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxOad.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer lo que deseas puedes hacer un código similar al siguiente:

```
const json = [{id: "1", description: "Desctiption", cost:13, category:"Autos"}, {id: "2", description: "Lorem ipsum", cost:15, category:"Motos"}, {id: "3", description: "Moto", cost:25, category:"Motos"}];

function filterByCategory(){
     let res = {};
     json.filter(function(element){
          if(!res[element.category]){
               res[element.category] = [element];   
          } else {
             res[element.category].push(element);
          };
    });

    Object.entries(res).forEach(category => {
         let text = category[0] + ": ";
         category[1].forEach(categoryContent => {
               Object.values(categoryContent).forEach(value => {
                   text += value +" ";
               });
               text += ", ";
         });
         console.log(text);
    });
}

filterByCategory(); //Probamos
```

Espero sea lo que buscas.

Comment: Es que no, mira yo estoy llamanso a los resultados mediante un for, si uso la funciona filterBy() deberia hacerlo manualmente, por ejemplo si quiero filtrar los autos tengo que hacer filterBy("category", "Autos");

Comment: Prueba nuevamente.

Comment: Ya debe estar funcionando como lo requieres.

Comment: si, algo asi, gracias, ya tengo la base, creo que puedo continuar

Comment: Perfecto, un gusto ser de ayuda.

Comment: una pregunta si el json fuera asi:  [{id: "1", description: "Desctiption", cost:13, "category":{ "t":"Autos"} }, {id: "2", description: "Lorem ipsum", cost:15,"category":{ "t":"Motos"}}, {id: "3", description: "Moto", cost:25, "category":{ "t":"Motos"}}]; seria posible seguir usando esa funcion ?

Comment: No, se dañaría al intentar graficar el objeto interno y saldría [Object object]

Answer (score 1):

Hola puedes usar la propiedad [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter). lo que hace es mediante una funcion te devuelve los que cumplen.

```js
var busca = "1";
busca = busca.toLowerCase();

var json = [{id: "1", description: "Desctiption", cost:13, category:"Autos"}, {id: "2", description: "Lorem ipsum", cost:15, category:"Motos"}, {id: "3", description: "Moto", cost:25, category:"Motos"}];


var filtrado = json.filter(function(element){
  var cumple = false;
  for(var key in element){
    if (element[key] && element[key].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(busca) > -1){
      cumple = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(cumple) { 
    return element;
  }
});

console.log(filtrado)
```

Comment: Entiendo y lo intenté hacer así, pero lo que yo quiero es que sea dinámico, osea... que se filtren todos automáticamente... no se si me estoy explicando bien.

Comment: No entiendo, quieres filtrar por el contenido de todos los atributos? como un like o que sea igual?

Comment: No, yo tengo un  for (var i = 0; i < res.feed.entry.length; i++) { } ahi tomo el valor de objetos y los imprimo en el html, lo que yo quiero es que cuando las categorias sean iguales me lo imprima en una sola linea, osea, que ordene los resultados por categoria y que me imprima solo una vez la categoria.

Comment: puedes colocar en la pregunta la imagen de como quieres que se veas el resultado final?

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver Creo que lo que el quiere es mostrar una sola linea agrupando

Comment: @Vanu pero al hacer esto, solo podras mostrar motos , no la descripcion , por que la descripcion es diferente o como quieres que se muestre la descripcion ?

Comment: ya subi la imagen de como quiero el resultado

Comment: Basicamente quiero agrupar a todos los que tengan las mismas categorias

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo, quieres agrupar por `category` se podría resolver bastante mas corto usando `reduce()`:

```js
const arr = [{"id":"1","description":"Desctiption","cost":13,"category":"Autos"},{"id":"2","description":"Lorem ipsum","cost":15,"category":"Motos"},{"id":"3","description":"Moto","cost":25,"category":"Motos"}];

const agrupado = Object.entries(arr.reduce((p, c) => {
  (c.category in p)?
    p[c.category] += ", " + c.description + " $" + c.cost:
    p[c.category] = c.description + " $" + c.cost;
  
  return p;
}, {})).map(e=>e.join(": ")).join(", ");

console.log(agrupado);
```

Agregué un `Object.entries()` junto con `join()` para que quede un solo `string` con todo.